# Regression ValueError: Pandas data cast to numpy dtype of object. Check input data with np.asarray(data)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, regression

I have a data frame 'df' that has missing column values. I want to fill in the missing/NaN values in the Avg Monthly Long Distance Charges column through prediction (regression) using the other column values. Then, replace the NaN values with the new values found.

I received the following error message when executing my code. Is there something that I am doing wrong?

Data frame: 'df'

```
Customer ID,Gender,Age,Married,Number of Dependents,City,Zip Code,Latitude,Longitude,Number of Referrals,Tenure in Months,Offer,Phone Service,Avg Monthly Long Distance Charges,Multiple Lines,Internet Service,Internet Type,Avg Monthly GB Download,Online Security,Online Backup,Device Protection Plan,Premium Tech Support,Streaming TV,Streaming Movies,Streaming Music,Unlimited Data,Contract,Paperless Billing,Payment Method,Monthly Charge,Total Charges,Total Refunds,Total Extra Data Charges,Total Long Distance Charges,Total Revenue,Customer Status,Churn Category,Churn Reason
0002-ORFBO,Female,37,Yes,0,Frazier Park,93225,34.827662,-118.999073,2,9,None,Yes,42.39,No,Yes,Cable,16,No,Yes,No,Yes,Yes,No,No,Yes,One Year,Yes,Credit Card,65.6,593.3,0,0,381.51,974.81,Stayed,,
0003-MKNFE,Male,46,No,0,Glendale,91206,34.162515,-118.203869,0,9,None,Yes,10.69,Yes,Yes,Cable,10,No,No,No,No,No,Yes,Yes,No,Month-to-Month,No,Credit Card,-4,542.4,38.33,10,96.21,610.28,Stayed,,
0004-TLHLJ,Male,50,No,0,Costa Mesa,92627,33.645672,-117.922613,0,4,Offer E,Yes,33.65,No,Yes,Fiber Optic,30,No,No,Yes,No,No,No,No,Yes,Month-to-Month,Yes,Bank Withdrawal,73.9,280.85,0,0,134.6,415.45,Churned,Competitor,Competitor had better devices
0011-IGKFF,Male,78,Yes,0,Martinez,94553,38.014457,-122.115432,1,13,Offer D,Yes,27.82,No,Yes,Fiber Optic,4,No,Yes,Yes,No,Yes,Yes,No,Yes,Month-to-Month,Yes,Bank Withdrawal,98,1237.85,0,0,361.66,1599.51,Churned,Dissatisfaction,Product dissatisfaction
0013-EXCHZ,Female,75,Yes,0,Camarillo,93010,34.227846,-119.079903,3,3,None,Yes,7.38,No,Yes,Fiber Optic,11,No,No,No,Yes,Yes,No,No,Yes,Month-to-Month,Yes,Credit Card,83.9,267.4,0,0,22.14,289.54,Churned,Dissatisfaction,Network reliability
0013-MHZWF,Female,23,No,3,Midpines,95345,37.581496,-119.972762,0,9,Offer E,Yes,16.77,No,Yes,Cable,73,No,No,No,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Month-to-Month,Yes,Credit Card,69.4,571.45,0,0,150.93,722.38,Stayed,,
0013-SMEOE,Female,67,Yes,0,Lompoc,93437,34.757477,-120.550507,1,71,Offer A,Yes,9.96,No,Yes,Fiber Optic,14,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Two Year,Yes,Bank Withdrawal,109.7,7904.25,0,0,707.16,8611.41,Stayed,,
0014-BMAQU,Male,52,Yes,0,Napa,94558,38.489789,-122.27011,8,63,Offer B,Yes,12.96,Yes,Yes,Fiber Optic,7,Yes,No,No,Yes,No,No,No,No,Two Year,Yes,Credit Card,84.65,5377.8,0,20,816.48,6214.28,Stayed,,
0015-UOCOJ,Female,68,No,0,Simi Valley,93063,34.296813,-118.685703,0,7,Offer E,Yes,10.53,No,Yes,DSL,21,Yes,No,No,No,No,No,No,Yes,Two Year,Yes,Bank Withdrawal,48.2,340.35,0,0,73.71,414.06,Stayed,,
0016-QLJIS,Female,43,Yes,1,Sheridan,95681,38.984756,-121.345074,3,65,None,Yes,28.46,Yes,Yes,Cable,14,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Two Year,Yes,Credit Card,90.45,5957.9,0,0,1849.9,7807.8,Stayed,,
0017-DINOC,Male,47,No,0,Rancho Santa Fe,92091,32.99356,-117.207121,0,54,None,No,,,Yes,Cable,10,Yes,No,No,Yes,Yes,No,No,Yes,Two Year,No,Credit Card,45.2,2460.55,0,0,0,2460.55,Stayed,,
0017-IUDMW,Female,25,Yes,2,Sunnyvale,94086,37.378541,-122.020456,2,72,None,Yes,16.01,Yes,Yes,Fiber Optic,59,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Two Year,Yes,Credit Card,116.8,8456.75,0,0,1152.72,9609.47,Stayed,,
0018-NYROU,Female,58,Yes,0,Antelope,95843,38.715498,-121.363411,0,5,None,Yes,18.65,No,Yes,Fiber Optic,10,No,No,No,No,No,No,No,Yes,Month-to-Month,Yes,Bank Withdrawal,68.95,351.5,0,0,93.25,444.75,Stayed,,
0019-EFAEP,Female,32,No,0,La Mesa,91942,32.782501,-117.01611,0,72,Offer A,Yes,2.25,Yes,Yes,Fiber Optic,16,Yes,Yes,Yes,No,Yes,No,No,Yes,Two Year,Yes,Bank Withdrawal,101.3,7261.25,0,0,162,7423.25,Stayed,,
0019-GFNTW,Female,39,No,0,Los Olivos,93441,34.70434,-120.02609,0,56,None,No,,,Yes,DSL,19,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,No,No,No,Yes,Two Year,No,Bank Withdrawal,45.05,2560.1,0,0,0,2560.1,Stayed,,
0020-INWCK,Female,58,Yes,2,Woodlake,93286,36.464635,-119.094348,9,71,Offer A,Yes,27.26,Yes,Yes,Fiber Optic,12,No,Yes,Yes,No,No,Yes,Yes,Yes,Two Year,Yes,Credit Card,95.75,6849.4,0,0,1935.46,8784.86,Stayed,,
0020-JDNXP,Female,52,Yes,1,Point Reyes Station,94956,38.060264,-122.830646,0,34,None,No,,,Yes,DSL,20,Yes,No,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,One Year,No,Credit Card,61.25,1993.2,0,0,0,1993.2,Stayed,,
0021-IKXGC,Female,72,No,0,San Marcos,92078,33.119028,-117.166036,0,1,Offer E,Yes,7.77,Yes,Yes,Fiber Optic,22,No,No,No,No,No,No,No,Yes,One Year,Yes,Bank Withdrawal,72.1,72.1,0,0,7.77,79.87,Joined,,
0022-TCJCI,Male,79,No,0,Daly City,94015,37.680844,-122.48131,0,45,None,Yes,10.67,No,Yes,DSL,17,Yes,No,Yes,No,No,Yes,No,Yes,One Year,No,Credit Card,62.7,2791.5,0,0,480.15,3271.65,Churned,Dissatisfaction,Limited range of services
```

My code:

```
# Let X = predictor variable and y = target variable
X2 = pd.DataFrame(df[['Monthly Charge', 'Total Revenue']])
y2 = pd.DataFrame(df[['Multiple Lines']])

# Add a constant variable to the predictor variables
X = sm.add_constant(X2)
model02 = sm.OLS(y2, X2).fit()
df['Multiple Lines'].fillna(sm.OLS(y2, X2).fit(), inplace=True)
```

Error Message: ValueError: Pandas data cast to numpy dtype of object. Check input data with np.asarray(data).

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/wv/42dn23fd1cb0czpvqdnb6zw00000gn/T/ipykernel_15181/1879921247.py in <module>
      5 # Add a constant variable to the predictor variables
      6 X = sm.add_constant(X2)
----> 7 model02 = sm.OLS(y2, X2).fit()
      8 df['Multiple Lines'].fillna(sm.OLS(y2, X2).fit(), inplace=True)

~/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/statsmodels/regression/linear_model.py in __init__(self, endog, exog, missing, hasconst, **kwargs)
    888                    "An exception will be raised in the next version.")
    889             warnings.warn(msg, ValueWarning)
--> 890         super(OLS, self).__init__(endog, exog, missing=missing,
    891                                   hasconst=hasconst, **kwargs)
    892         if "weights" in self._init_keys:

~/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/statsmodels/regression/linear_model.py in __init__(self, endog, exog, weights, missing, hasconst, **kwargs)
    715         else:
    716             weights = weights.squeeze()
--> 717         super(WLS, self).__init__(endog, exog, missing=missing,
    718                                   weights=weights, hasconst=hasconst, **kwargs)
    719         nobs = self.exog.shape[0]

~/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/statsmodels/regression/linear_model.py in __init__(self, endog, exog, **kwargs)
    189     """
    190     def __init__(self, endog, exog, **kwargs):
--> 191         super(RegressionModel, self).__init__(endog, exog, **kwargs)
    192         self._data_attr.extend(['pinv_wexog', 'wendog', 'wexog', 'weights'])
    193 

~/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/statsmodels/base/model.py in __init__(self, endog, exog, **kwargs)
    265 
    266     def __init__(self, endog, exog=None, **kwargs):
--> 267         super().__init__(endog, exog, **kwargs)
    268         self.initialize()
    269 

~/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/statsmodels/base/model.py in __init__(self, endog, exog, **kwargs)
     90         missing = kwargs.pop('missing', 'none')
     91         hasconst = kwargs.pop('hasconst', None)
---> 92         self.data = self._handle_data(endog, exog, missing, hasconst,
     93                                       **kwargs)
     94         self.k_constant = self.data.k_constant

~/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/statsmodels/base/model.py in _handle_data(self, endog, exog, missing, hasconst, **kwargs)
    130 
    131     def _handle_data(self, endog, exog, missing, hasconst, **kwargs):
--> 132         data = handle_data(endog, exog, missing, hasconst, **kwargs)
    133         # kwargs arrays could have changed, easier to just attach here
    134         for key in kwargs:

~/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/statsmodels/base/data.py in handle_data(endog, exog, missing, hasconst, **kwargs)
    671 
    672     klass = handle_data_class_factory(endog, exog)
--> 673     return klass(endog, exog=exog, missing=missing, hasconst=hasconst,
    674                  **kwargs)

~/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/statsmodels/base/data.py in __init__(self, endog, exog, missing, hasconst, **kwargs)
     80             self.orig_endog = endog
     81             self.orig_exog = exog
---> 82             self.endog, self.exog = self._convert_endog_exog(endog, exog)
     83 
     84         self.const_idx = None

~/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/statsmodels/base/data.py in _convert_endog_exog(self, endog, exog)
    505         exog = exog if exog is None else np.asarray(exog)
    506         if endog.dtype == object or exog is not None and exog.dtype == object:
--> 507             raise ValueError("Pandas data cast to numpy dtype of object. "
    508                              "Check input data with np.asarray(data).")
    509         return super(PandasData, self)._convert_endog_exog(endog, exog)

ValueError: Pandas data cast to numpy dtype of object. Check input data with np.asarray(data).
```

Comment: the code works for me . sm - 0.12.0 and pandas - 1.4.2

Comment: @srinath Sorry, I inputted the wrong line. The updated code does not run for me. Could you please check if it works for you? Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Building multi-regression model throws error: \`Pandas data cast to numpy dtype of object. Check input data with np.asarray(data).\`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33833832/building-multi-regression-model-throws-error-pandas-data-cast-to-numpy-dtype-o)

Comment: @srinath I changed the last line to `df['Multiple Lines'].fillna(sm.OLS(y2.astype(float), X2.astype(float)).fit(), inplace=True)`, but am still receiving the error. When adding `.astype(float)` to the lines above as well, I received another error message: ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'No'.

Answer (score 0):

your y variable (y2) is of type object. Before feeding into the model, convert the y variable to int/float.

For example

`model02 = sm.OLS(pd.get_dummies(y2), X2).fit()`

`pd.get_dummies` is one option. find the one which is more appropriate to your use case . For ex: [Label encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24458645/label-encoding-across-multiple-columns-in-scikit-learn)